# Problem with pmatrix

Tags: matrices

I'm trying to use pmatrix as follows:

```
\begin{equation}\label{Eq.11}
J =
\begin{pmatrix}
  \frac{\partial c_{1}(t+1)}{\partial c_{1}(t)} & \frac{\partial c_{1}(t+1)}{\partial c_{2}(t)} & \cdots & \frac{\partial c_{1}(t+1)}{\partial c_{L}(t)} \\
  \frac{\partial c_{2}(t+1)}{\partial c_{1}(t)} & \frac{\partial c_{2}(t+1)}{\partial c_{2}(t)} & \cdots & \frac{\partial c_{2}(t+1)}{\partial c_{L}(t)} \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  \frac{\partial c_{L}(t+1)}{\partial c_{1}(t)} & \frac{\partial c_{L}(t+1)}{\partial c_{2}(t)} & \cdots & \frac{\partial c_{L}(t+1)}{\partial c_{L}(t)} 
 \end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}
```

The following errors appears:

```
! Extra \right.\endpmatrix -> \endmatrix \right ) \end{pmatrix}
! Missing $ inserted.<inserted text>$ \end{pmatrix}
! Missing } inserted.<inserted text>} \end{pmatrix}
! You can't use `\eqno' in math mode.\endmathdisplay@a ...\df@tag \@empty \else \veqno\alt@tag \df@tag \fi \ifx ... \end{equation}
! Missing \right. inserted.<inserted text>\right . \end{equation}
! Missing \endgroup inserted.<inserted text>\endgroup \end{equation}
```

This code works fine in other documents, but the last document I'm working on consists of several files each of which represents a chapter in the document.

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please always post complete small documents that show the error. You should be able to add `\documentclass` and whatever is needed to your fragment so that we can reproduce the problem locally.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your code works fine for me. Add some additional information, as @David said.

Comment: Almost certainly the error is _before_ that quoted section (for instance a lone `$` before it would make TeX get out of sync with math mode commands not in math, which would make similar errors to this. (Although what are shown are not TeX errors, they have been filtered through some editor)

Answer (score 1):

Please always post *complete* documents which generate the error. In particular it allows you to check that the fragment you are posting does in fact generate an error. The fragment in your question does not generate an error, also the error messages are not complete TeX error messages.

However I would guess your real document os something like this, which makes similar errors, here I show the full TeX error which is more informative than the filtered view:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

$\left(     % unfinished math expression
\begin{equation}\label{Eq.11}
J =
\begin{pmatrix}
  \frac{\partial c_{1}(t+1)}{\partial c_{1}(t)} & \frac{\partial c_{1}(t+1)}{\partial c_{2}(t)} & \cdots & \frac{\partial c_{1}(t+1)}{\partial c_{L}(t)} \\
  \frac{\partial c_{2}(t+1)}{\partial c_{1}(t)} & \frac{\partial c_{2}(t+1)}{\partial c_{2}(t)} & \cdots & \frac{\partial c_{2}(t+1)}{\partial c_{L}(t)} \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  \frac{\partial c_{L}(t+1)}{\partial c_{1}(t)} & \frac{\partial c_{L}(t+1)}{\partial c_{2}(t)} & \cdots & \frac{\partial c_{L}(t+1)}{\partial c_{L}(t)} 
 \end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Makes the following errors (in TeX *always* look at the first error first, as in this case all following errors are spurious)

```
! LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.7 \begin{equation}
                    \label{Eq.11}
? 
! You can't use `\eqno' in math mode.
\endmathdisplay@a ...\df@tag \@empty \else \veqno 
                                                  \alt@tag \df@tag \fi \ifx ...
l.15 \end{equation}

? 
! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.15 \end{equation}

? 
! Missing \right. inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \right .
l.15 \end{equation}

? 

! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{equation}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.15 \end{equation}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response Mr. David. Still, I don't think this is the problem. When I put the matrix sentence between \iffalse and

Comment: @Yousef If you do not show a document that generates the error you can't expect people to guess what you have done wrong. _every_ question should include an full example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` Please fix your question.